# Adding multiple rows to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I know two ways to add new row with data to a `DataTable`

```
string[] arr2 = { "one", "two", "three" };
dtDeptDtl.Columns.Add("Dept_Cd");
```

---

```
for (int a = 0; a < arr2.Length; a++)
{
    DataRow dr2 = dtDeptDtl.NewRow();
    dr2["Dept_Cd"] = DeptCd[a];
    dtDeptDtl.Rows.Add(dr2);
}
```

---

```
for (int a = 0; a < arr2.Length; a++)
{
    dtDeptDtl.Rows.Add();
    dtDeptDtl.Rows[a]["Dept_Cd"] = DeptCd[a];
}
```

Both the above methods will give me the same result i.e One Two Three will be added in `DataTable` in seperate rows.

But my question is that what is the difference between both the steps and which one is better way performance wise?

Comment: You also need to add new column to existing datatable?

Comment: you can do it like `foreach (var item in arr2){ dtDeptDtl.Rows.Add(item);}`

Comment: The first approach will be faster.

Comment: can u plz justify why???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Some decompiler observations**

In both scenarios, a different overload of the `System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add` method is being used.

The first approach uses:

```
public void Add(DataRow row)
{
    this.table.AddRow(row, -1);
}
```

The second approach will use:

```
public DataRow Add(params object[] values)
{
    int record = this.table.NewRecordFromArray(values);
    DataRow dataRow = this.table.NewRow(record);
    this.table.AddRow(dataRow, -1);
    return dataRow;
}
```

Now, take a look at this little beast:

```
internal int NewRecordFromArray(object[] value)
{
    int count = this.columnCollection.Count;
    if (count < value.Length)
    {
        throw ExceptionBuilder.ValueArrayLength();
    }
    int num = this.recordManager.NewRecordBase();
    int result;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if (value[i] != null)
            {
                this.columnCollection[i][num] = value[i];
            }
            else
            {
                this.columnCollection[i].Init(num);
            }
        }
        for (int j = value.Length; j < count; j++)
        {
            this.columnCollection[j].Init(num);
        }
        result = num;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (ADP.IsCatchableOrSecurityExceptionType(e))
        {
            this.FreeRecord(ref num);
        }
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Especially, note the `this.columnCollection[i][num] = value[i];`, which will call:

```
public DataColumn this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        DataColumn result;
        try
        {
            result = (DataColumn)this._list[index];
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ColumnOutOfRange(index);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Moving forward, we discover that actually `_list` is an `ArrayList`:

```
private readonly ArrayList _list = new ArrayList();
```

**Conclusion**

In order to summarize the above, if you are using `dtDeptDtl.Rows.Add();` instead of `dtDeptDtl.Rows.Add(dr2);`, you will get a **performance degradation** which will increase exponentially, as the number of columns grows. The responsible line for the degradation is call to the `NewRecordFromArray` method, which iterates over an `ArrayList`.

*Note: This can be easily tested if you add, let's say, 8 columns to the table and make some tests in a `for` looping 1000000 times.*