# Add multiple rows into datatable with the same data without looping

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to add multiple rows with the same content without loop?

The following is the code I am currently using to achieve this.

```
        DataTable dtMessageDetails = new DataTable("Private Message Details");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dtMessageDetails.Rows.Add("65E6BD38-2806-S15G-9DC5-9DE908333996", 3, 0, "News", "News", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), "Publish", "mes", 0, 0, 0, "null", "null", "Active");
        }
```

And my datatable should looks like

[image]

I want to replace loop with some other approach may be LINQ.

Comment: What's wrong with loop?

Comment: I think I have to be more clear. I need fastest way to achieve that because the datatable will have more than 10000 rows. So for better performance, I like to avoid looping.

Comment: I think performance will not be an issue.

Comment: Linq will not be faster than simple loop (I think nothing will be faster than `for` loop). One question - why you need to create datatable with 10000 duplicated rows?

Comment: Is this ok to use loop even it is more than 50000 rows? Do you mean that it wont affect performance?

Comment: Again, why you are creating this table? You want to display it in some GridView?

Comment: @Sudha: I guess what you're looking for is the most efficient way to insert duplicate rows in the database, since it is not possible to perform that without loops. A loop has got to exist somewhere! even if it is not in your code it will exist somewhere else (in a library or even in hardware!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @lazyberezovsky's answer, I recommend you to use the [DataRowCollection.Add Method (DataRow)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload, which is [slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465931/674700):

```
var itemArray = new object[] { 
    "65E6BD38-2806-S15G-9DC5-9DE908333996", 3, 0, "News", "News", 
    Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    "Publish", "mes", 0, 0, 0, "null", "null", "Active" };

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var r = dtMessageDetails.NewRow();
    r.ItemArray = itemArray;
    dtMessageDetails.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

If you intend to add the same rows to a new `DataTable` instance through your code, you might also get some performance improvement if you use the [DataTable.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx). Just create the rows above once in your code, then use the following to populate another datatable:

```
var dtMessageDetailsCopy = dtMessageDetails.Copy();
```

Comment: Didn't know about NewRecordFromArray beast. Good point, skipping items array check will be faster

Answer (score 3):

Linq is for querying data, not for inserting. You can prepare data with linq, but you will use same loop for adding rows, which will not be any faster. Thus you are inserting same data, I suggest you to prepare these data instead of creating new items array on each iteration:

```
DataTable dtMessageDetails = new DataTable("Private Message Details");
object[] items = { "65E6BD38-2806-S15G-9DC5-9DE908333996", 3, 0, "News", "News", 
                   Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), 
                   "Publish", "mes", 0, 0, 0, "null", "null", "Active" };

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    
    dtMessageDetails.Rows.Add(items);
```