# converting excel macro to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio, vsto

i am creating VSTO in excel , for this i am converting the existing macro to c# where  have to find minimun of the column , i have converted this far as shown below  :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace CpCpk
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            var excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
            //excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            excelApp.Range["P2"].Select();
            excelApp.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])";
            excelApp.Range["Q2"].Select();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

now i am not getting any error in syntax , but during execution i am getting below rror:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveCell''
```

in the line :

```
excelApp.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])";
```

somebody please help me how to correct this..

Comment: try excelApp.Range["P2"].FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])";

Comment: also @matmahnke please change your comment as answer so that i can mark the same

Comment: sorry i don't know anything about excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `FormulaR1C1` directly from specific cell

```
excelApp.Range["P2"].FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the spreadsheet to a datatable [via closed xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756449/read-excel-worksheet-into-datatable-using-closedxml) (via nuget) like so:

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromExcel(string path, dynamic worksheet)
    {
        //Save the uploaded Excel file.


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(worksheet);

            //Create a new DataTable.

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, dt.Columns.Count))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            toInsert[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(toInsert);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Then get the minimum via linq:

```
var min = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Min(r  => r.Field<Decimal>(col));
```

Reminder, you'll need `using System.Linq;` and using `ClosedXML.Excel;`

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but the above solution in comment worked for me..