# How to convert an Excel file to .CSV using ClosedXML for un-structured data

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, epplus, closedxml

I have a scenario where I need to convert an MS Excel file to .CSV format in Net core 3.1 application. The data in the Excel file is not in tabular format, some places having merged cells or some headers information and then tabular data.

I tried to read that data and put it in a DataTable using ClosedXMl but it treats it differently since the initial few rows are not in line with the rest of the data which causes trimming a few columns.

My Excel looks like

[image]

Here, the first 2 rows are spanned across 3 columns only.

Below is my code using closedXML.

```
public static DataTable GetData(string filename)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
            using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(filename))
            {
                //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
                IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
                //Create a new DataTable.

                //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
                int rowsToSkip = 1;
                foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
                {

                    var cellsCount = row.Cells().Count();

                    ////Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                    if (rowsToSkip <= 3)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                toInsert[i] =Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //Handle this, or don't.
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(toInsert);
                    }
                    rowsToSkip++;
                }


                return dt;
            }
        }



        public static void ToCSV(DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
            //headers    
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
                if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {
                        string value = dr[i].ToString();
                        if (value.Contains(','))
                        {
                            value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                            sw.Write(value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
```

In GetData(), it only creates 3 columns in the data table since initial rows are spanned across 3 columns only.

I highly appreciate any inputs to handle this scenario when I can put unstructured data in the data table and write to CSV.  I am open to other open-source packages too like EPPlus 4.5 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a month old question, hopefully you still need an answer.

First off, for your closedxml code, I noticed it's a slightly modified version of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756449/read-excel-worksheet-into-datatable-using-closedxml/48758358). Just want to quickly say the accepted answer there isn't the best as it throws null reference exceptions if there are blank rows at the bottom of the spreadsheet. Happens rarely, but it does still happen. Because of this, I'm going to be using a modified version of the unaccepted answer on the same question.

Your code isn't adding the correct headers because you're adding columns for rows 1-3 because of this:
`if (rowsToSkip <= 3)`

I've created the following spreadsheet:
[image]

Using this method, it imports correctly.

```
    public static DataTable ImportExcel(string path)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool addRows = false;
            int rowCount = 1;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //If we're on row 3, add headers and toggle flag to addRows.
                if (rowCount == 3)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    addRows = true;
                }
                else if (addRows)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, dt.Columns.Count))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            toInsert[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Handle this.
                            //Log it or throw
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(toInsert);
                }
                rowCount++;
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

I used your CSV code, but I'd suggest using something like CSVHelper in the future just to help account for any unknowns that may pop up in the future.

Output file:
[image]